# Observable of <any[]> to Array[]

Tags: angular

I'm trying to transform my data using pipes. The pipes work fine in html but don't want to work when used in a component. I get the following error:
'Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable'.'

Component.ts:

```
this.locationChangeForUserObservable = fucareDatabaseService.getLocationChangesForUser('user1' + '/locationChange');
this.list = new WeekFilterPipe().transform(this.locationChangeForUserObservable, 'datum', this.mondayInMS);
this.list = new CalculateWeekPipe().transform(this.locationChangeForUserObservable, this.mondayInMS);
```

My pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'weekFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class WeekFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }

    if (!field || !value) {
      return items;
    }

    var monday = moment(value);
    var tuesday = moment(monday).add('24', 'hours');
    var wednesday = moment(monday).add('48', 'hours');
    var thursday = moment(monday).add('72', 'hours');
    var friday = moment(monday).add('96', 'hours');
    var saturday = moment(monday).add('120', 'hours');
    var sunday = moment(monday).add('144', 'hours');
    monday = monday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    tuesday = tuesday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    wednesday = wednesday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    thursday = thursday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    friday = friday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    saturday = saturday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    sunday = sunday.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    return items.filter(item => {
      if (item[field].includes(monday) || item[field].includes(tuesday) ||
        item[field].includes(wednesday) || item[field].includes(thursday)
        || item[field].includes(friday) || item[field].includes(saturday) || item[field].includes(sunday))  {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }


@Pipe({
  name: 'calculateWeekPipe'
})
@Injectable()
export class CalculateWeekPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transformDate(datum) {
    var temp = datum.split(' ')[0];
    var temp = temp.split('-');

    return temp.reverse().join('-') + ' ' + datum.split(' ')[1];
  }
  getDay(item) {

    var datum = item.datum;
    if (typeof datum === 'undefined') {
      console.log('damn');
    }
   ...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error states that you are passing in an Observable when the `transform` function expects an array. `this.list = new WeekFilterPipe().transform(this.locationChangeForUserObservable...` Here you can see you are passing in an observable as the first parameter but it should be an array.

Comment: Does the observable `locationChangeForUserObservable` return the array that you need to pass to the transform method?

Comment: @LLai The LocationChangeForUserObservable gets its value from this method:
    getLocationChangesForUser(user){
      console.log(user);
      this.locationChangeForUserObservable = this.db.list('users/' + user).valueChanges();
      return this.locationChangeForUserObservable;
    }
However I have no idea how to transform it to an array

Comment: Armen has the answer. You need to subscribe to the observable, transform the returned data to an array (if needed), then run your transform method

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transform an Observable to an Array, as it is asynchronous, but you can subscribe to the observable and pass the emitted value to the pipe function:

```
this.locationChangeForUserObservable.subscribe(locationChanges => {
    this.list = new CalculateWeekPipe().transform(locationChanges , this.mondayInMS);
});
```

For example.

Of course, if this observable returns precisely the array you need to pass to the pipe function. Otherwise, you may need some transformations (`map`, `toArray` maybe, depends on the actual emitted value)